# Cabal Install Failing OSX

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Whenever i try to run `cabal install` i get the following

```
/var/folders/_3/48klb5054_jbgzrd7xr05_z80000gn/T/32059.c:1:12:
     warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo() {}
           ^
```

Comment: I don't think that's an error message. I'm pretty sure I've seen that message on builds that work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the problem is in the installation of system-filepath (which itself might be a problem finding the proper text package).  The c stuff at the top seems to be just a warning, so you can probably ignore it.

Generally, when this happens to me, I do the following to get to the underlying cause of the problem.

1. First just try a direct install of the underlying library with the problem (this usually doesn't work, but on a couple of occasions it mysteriously does).

   cabal install system-filepath
2. Then, download the source code (this is really easy using `cabal unpack`) and try to install it by hand.

   cabal unpack system-filepath
   cd system-filepath*
   cabal configure
   cabal build
   cabal install

The last three lines could be simplified to just `cabal install`, but the whole purpose of this excercise is to isolate where the problem occurs.  You will almost definitely learn more about the problem from the message you get.  Often the problem is a missing OS c library or its headers.

1. If you still have a problem, try something more drastic (if you have the guts :) ).  Empty your ~/.cabal/ and/or ~/.ghc/ subdirs (actually, just move them to a safe place, in case you decide to put them back).  You may need to keep the contents of ~/.cabal/bin/, but you shouldn't need anything else.  Try the install again.
2. If you still are lost, come back here, but this time update with the info you learned from this process.  This new info may give us what we need to fix the problem.

Comment: if i download the source for cabal-install would it fix this for future usage?

Comment: also it breaks on cabal configure

Comment: same as before (comment to short)

Comment: That is the warning....  I don't think it matters.  If you look below, you should see the error.